# Span tag with display:inline rendering as display:block

Tags: html, css, jsp

I have a span tag like this

```
<td>
<s:textfield name="trnfr" id="trnfr"/>
<span id="trnfrm" style="width:10px;display:inline;">
  &nbsp;
  <a onClick="showCal('trnfrm')"><img src="./images/cal.gif" border="0"
  alt='<s:text name="Co.Cal" />' /> </a>
</span>
</td>
```

It should render as

[image]

but it is rendering like this

[image]

when i viewed the source in the browser it is being rendered like this

[image]

Dont know whats going wrong.

Note: I got the correct image by changing display:block to display:inline dynamically in the browser.

Comment: Sounds like some JavaScript is turning it into block. Can you show us the JS relevant to it, if any? If not, try `float: left`

Comment: @Chen Asraf: It was a JS overriding it to block found the root cause. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren't able to easily override in your CSS because the element is being set to `display:block` inline (within your HTML), likely by the framework you are using (hard to say without further detail).

As such you will either need to prevent this from being set, remove it (i.e. using JS) or override it in your CSS.

To override in your CSS, you will need to use `!important`, e.g:

```
#trnfrm{
  display:inline!important;
}
```

That said, note that the use of `!important` is [not recommended](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#The_!important_exception). Ideally you should look to fix the root cause.

> When an `!important` rule is used on a style declaration, this
>   declaration overrides any other declaration made in the CSS, wherever
>   it is in the declaration list. Although, `!important` has nothing to do
>   with specificity.  Using !important is bad practice because it makes
>   debugging hard since you break the natural cascading in your
>   stylesheets.

Comment: This worked for me. Will try to find the root cause though thanks.

Comment: @BaN3 - not at all, glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Inserting anchor tag and img tag inside span tag is not an ideal way of coding. Wrap them inside a div tag which is a block element and style for the class "trnfr" and div should be display:inline-block".

Comment: Edited answer is posted.

Answer (score -2):

This is CSS issue for sure. Please provide some more data.